# How to replace all occurrences of an array?

Tags: javascript

I have 2 arrays,

the first one is like this `var symbols = ['A', 'B'];` and the second one like this `var num = ['3', 'A', '5', '4'];`

I need a way to replace every element in `num` that's also present in `symbols` with the value of the index of the element in `symbol` + 10.

In this case i need to get

`num = ['3', '10', '5', '4']`

How can i replace all the occurrences?

Comment: Could you please share the code , what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

This is very basic question so you should first at least try to search for an answer yourself.

but here you go

```
result = num.map((n) => {
    const index = symbols.indexOf(n);
    return index === -1 ? n : index + 10;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a handful of ways to do this. Some more efficient than others.

```
let symbols = ['A', 'B'];
let num = ['3', 'A', '5', '4'];
//Make a new array by only keeping the ones that are not found in the other array. This method does it by value
let numsWithAllSymbolsRemoved = nums.filter(element=> symbols.indexOf(element) == -1) 
// Now numsWithAllSymbolsRemoved = ['3', '10', '5', '4']

//Mutate the existing array, by index. 
for( let i = 0; i < num.length; i++){
  // If the item in num array has a index that's not -1 (if it's not found, that's what indexOf returns
  if ( symbols.indexOf(num[i]) !== -1) {
    nums.splice(i, 1); // Actually modify the array by splicing out the current index.
  }
}
 // Now num = ['3', '10', '5', '4']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try making a map using `symbols` array where you store element and it's corresponding index and then use this `symbolMap` map to get your desired result in `num` array.

```
let symbolMap = new Map();
symbols.forEach((symbol, index) => symbolMap.set(symbol, index));

num.forEach((n, index) => {
    if (symbolMap.has(n)) {
        num[index] = symbolMap.get(n) + 10
    }
})
```

I am mutating the original array here. You can choose to use `.map()` instead of `.forEach()` if you don't want to mutate original array.

```
let newNum = num.map((n) => {
    if (symbolMap.has(n)) {
        return symbolMap.get(n) + 10
    }
   return n
})
```